# Can anyone explain what these errors mean. I thought these were framework / linking errors but adding framework didnt fix

Tags: iphone

```
".objc_class_name_UILabel", referenced from:
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UILabel in libSCKitAppName.a(SCStretchableControl.o)

".objc_class_name_CAKeyframeAnimation", referenced from:
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CAKeyframeAnimation in libSCKitAppName.a(CAAnimationAdditions.o)

".objc_class_name_NSMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableURLRequest in libSCFoundationAppName.a(SCFileDownloadOperation.o)
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableURLRequest in libSCFoundationAppName.a(SCStorePurchaseOperation.o)
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableURLRequest in libPMAnalytics-r69.a(Beacon.o)
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableURLRequest in libPMAnalytics-r69.a(PMFBRequest.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLDocument", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref-to-XMLDocument in GPPublicationIssue.o
    objc-class-ref-to-XMLDocument in GPIssueIngestOperation.o

".objc_class_name_UIActivityIndicatorView", referenced from:
    literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIActivityIndicatorView in libSCKitAppName.a(SCZoomableView.o)

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCParserObject", referenced from:
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPItemListParserObject in GPItemListParserObject.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreBodyDescription in GPStoreBodyDescription.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreHeaderBrickList in GPStoreHeaderBrickList.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreHeaderDescription in GPStoreHeaderDescription.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreHeaderProductDetailDescription in GPStoreHeaderProductDetailDescription.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreItem in GPStoreItem.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStorePageDescription in GPStorePageDescription.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreRootParserObject in GPStoreRootParserObject.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreHeaderPreviewPageList in GPStoreHeaderPreviewPageList.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreHeaderPreviewPageDescription in GPStoreHeaderPreviewPageDescription.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPStoreHeaderTitleSectionDescription in GPStoreHeaderTitleSectionDescription.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPIssueInfo in GPIssueInfo.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPIssueInfoRootParserObject in GPIssueInfoRootParserObject.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryRateSection in GPLibraryRateSection.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryNextIssueSection in GPLibraryNextIssueSection.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryRelatedSection in GPLibraryRelatedSection.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryAfterReaderRoot in GPLibraryAfterReaderRoot.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryAfterReaderPage in GPLibraryAfterReaderPage.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryShareSection in GPLibraryShareSection.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPLibraryAction in GPLibraryAction.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPNewsPageRootObject in GPNewsPageRootObject.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPNewsBrickSection in GPNewsBrickSection.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPNewsNewsSection in GPNewsNewsSection.o
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPNewsPage in GPNewsPage.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCImageLoadOperation", referenced from:
```

Comment: They probably are linking errors. Try removing and re-adding all the frameworks, and also clean the build and delete the product

Answer (score 0):

Those in fact are linking errors. Make sure that you have the latest iOS SDK selected for both project and Target. Also make sure that there are no missing items in your Project Browser.